# Hundreds of subdomains dynamic mapping to Azure

Tags: azure, mapping, dns, cname

I'm building SaaS solution that gives our clients possibility to build online landing pages. The service provides tools to build and hosts landing pages. We need to give our clients option to connect their own domain names to the pages they built. Let say the service domain is www.abc.com used for Azure. Every client has local URL www.abc.com/client. However, usually clients want to be able to use own domains like www.client.com instead of our local URL. Of course we can instruct them to add  CNAME that points www.client.com to our Azure site. The problem is that Azure also requires to add every domain manually.

Is there a solution to pass this stage some way? Let's say we'd know the clients domains asking them to provide the domains in their profiles. How could we supply the domains to Azure dynamically and not manually? This is the question. Having at least 100+ clients make manual entry impossible. I'd appreciate any recommendations and solution to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about Windows Azure Web Sites. Automating CNAME management is not possible at the moment, you'll have to add them manually in the portal. At the moment there is [a limited API](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/cli/commands/site.js) to work with Web Sites, but it's not documented. So maybe the CNAME management will be possible through this API once it goes public, but no way to know for sure at the moment.

Another solution would be to use a Web Role instead of a Web Site. This will allow your customers to map whatever CNAME they want to **yourapplication.cloudapp.net** and it will simply work. Then in your code you could use [Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx) (assuming you're using ASP.NET MVC) to map domains in your application.